# Cost effective way to communicate data between a force resistor and a raspberry pi / Arduino

Tags: arduino, rf, raspberry-pi, wifi, bluetooth-low-energy

I am looking for a cost effective way to communicate data between a force sensitive resistor [FSR402](http://www.interlinkelectronics.com/FSR402.php) to a raspberry pi/Arduino wirelessly. I am open to using BLE / WiFi / Radio Communication.

The solution at FSR area needs to be optimized for power consumptions. Ideally, the circuit only needs to wake when the main controller is looking at the data.

Comment: So, given that shopping questions are off-topic, what is your actual question? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What range? i.e. 5 meters open space, 12 meters through walls etc. And what bandwidth? One reading per second, one per milisecond, one per minute etc.

Comment: 12 meter will do the work

Comment: If you need the device to save power and sleep, you can rule anything out with a big operating system like the Pi. Instead, you have to look at small micro-controllers like the Arduino. There are other options too including zigbee devices which are short range low bandwidth mesh capable wireless devices. There are integrated devices which have the radio and a small micro-controller integrated with PWM, analog and digital I/O's. Digi sells these little boards which do just that. They can be powered by a few AA batteries and depending on use, the batteries can last years.

Comment: The cheapest way to do what you want is probably to use a small microcontroller with built in ADC, and a bluetooth low energy or zigbee radio. Program the micro to go into sleep mode, and wake on an interrupt from the radio chip/module when it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

The ESP8266 chip has quickly become very popular for simple, small-scale wireless solutions such as your scenario.  There are dozens of people offering boards using that chip in various combinations.

Note that you will need to leave it running continuously (very wasteful of power) if you want to "poll" it from the main controller.  OTOH, if you only need readings every "n" seconds or minutes or hours, then it would be much more practical to have your remote wireless unit wake up and "push" data on some regular schedule.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266